# Types of Function in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me with the types of function available in SQL server.
And differences among them.

I am a newbie to SQL so do not know much about it, any help will be thankful.

Comment: Is this homework?  It has a homeworky vibe.

Comment: Question is to broad. Be more specific, what do you need and why?

Comment: Hello, I am new to SQL. @MJH

Comment: Try this series of videos on YouTube, they are aimed at beginners:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BslHItOTjU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: types of function available in SQL server.]

And differences among them.
And best practice how and where to use it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql

Hope this will help.